# How to copy values (from languages which are not English) from one xlsx file to another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xlsx

I've been trying to create an application which copies cell values from one xlsx file to another, though the column numbers are specific so there are a lot of values which makes it more complicated.
The problem is that the Debugger always stops the application and says that "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference".
Though it is weird because when I use the Console.WriteLine command to tell me the values of i,y,z and that cell, all of those are ok, though the cell value is somehow ??? ?????? ?? which doesn't make sense. (The cell value is in Hebrew).
How do I fix this? And how do I tell the application that if it reaches a cell which is null - copy nothing into the new cell, instead of crashing?
Here is the Code:

```
int imin= 3;
int ymin= 13;
int by= 0;
string[] ids= new string[208];
string[] headlines = new string[406];
string company;
string date;
string str_dir_folder;
string str_dir_file;
string sheet_name;

private void button_activate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int z = 1;
        sheet_name = textbox_sheet.Text;
        Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
        ExcelApp.Interactive = false;
        Excel.Workbook wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(str_dir_file, Missing.Value, false, Missing.Value,
        Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            Excel.Worksheet sh = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[sheet_name];
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Interactive = false;
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;

            for (int i = imin; i < max_line; i++)
            {
                if (sh.Cells[i, 150].Value.ToString() != null)
                {
                    ids[i - imin] = sh.Cells[i, 150].Value.ToString();
                    for (int y = ymin; y < max_line; y++)
                    {
                        if (y != 76 && y != 108 && y != 112 && y != 114 && y != 125 && y != 128 && y != 129 && y != 131 && y != 142 && y != 149 && y != 151
                            && y != 157 && y !=
                            186 && y != 188 && y != 189 && y != 190 && y != 191 && y != 197 && y != 199 && y != 200 && y != 202 && y != 203
                            && y != 204 && y != 205 && y != 214 && y != 215 && y != 231 && y != 233 && y != 255 && y != 280 && y != 285 && (y > 12) ||
                            (y > 62 && y < 80) || (y > 88 && y < 133) || (y > 139 && y < 170) || (y > 183 && y < 208) || (y > 212 && y < 217) || (y > 229 && y < 407))
                        {
                            if (y == 13) company = sh.Cells[i, 13].Value.ToString();
                            headlines[y - ymin] = sh.Cells[1, y].Value.ToString();
                            workSheet.Cells[2, z].Value = sh.Cells[i, y].Value.ToString();
                            workSheet.Cells[1, z].Value = headlines[y - ymin];
                            workSheet.Columns[z].AutoFit();
                            z++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Directory.CreateDirectory(str_dir_folder + ids[i - imin]);
                date = DateTime.Today.Day + "." + DateTime.Today.Month + "." + DateTime.Today.Year + "_" +
                DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "_" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond + "_" + by;
                workSheet.SaveAs((str_dir_folder + ids[i - imin] + @"/" + date + "-" + company + ".xlsx"), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value,
                Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                by++;
            }
            ExcelApp.Workbooks.Close();
            ExcelApp.Quit();
            excelApp.Workbooks.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: The question marks are caused either by using a font that doesn't support those characters or (more likely) treating the text as ASCII when it;s something else (like UTF-8). There's a fair chance the problem is with viewing the value, not with the value itself (eg the standard windows console doesn't support UTF-8). If you can identify the specific line causing the problem, it seems more likely that you're referring to an object/cell incorrectly (or before it's been assigned a value). This is a great intro to unicode and how/why it (mostly) works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4

Comment: This is the cell which gives me errors
[image](http://prntscr.com/d31c9g)
The Font is Calibri

Comment: I've used this way of referring to a cell before and it works just fine.
Actually, everything works except for
    workSheet.Cells[2, z].Value = sh.Cells[i, y].Value.ToString();

Comment: Another problem is that if the code is trying to access a null cell, the application will stop for the same reason.
Example of a null cell: [Image](http://prntscr.com/d31hn8)

Comment: When I said font, I meant of the console/etc where you're seeing the ???'s. Re: empty cells, that makes sense... If `sh.Celss[,].Value` is null, calling `.ToString()` on it will result in a `NullReferenceException`. You should be doing a check in there... `var cellValue = sh.Cells[,].Value; if(cellValue != null) { ... }`, but I don't think that's the only problem. Otherwise, it would work with non-empty cells.

Comment: So i shouldn't use the .ToString() method?

Comment: When I take off the ToString(), the Debugger says that the cell value is double and it cannot convert it to string.
Is there no way around this?

Comment: You shouldn't use `.ToString()` on an object that might be null. (But that applies to all methods!). Depending on the version of C# you're using, there's something called the [Null Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx) which handles this case for you. Yes, to convert a double to a string, you need to provide a format. Eg the following will include separators for thousands and one digit after the decimal point... `String.Format("{0:#,#.0}", myValue)`. See http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/ for more examples

Comment: Should I set ids, headlines and company to vars?

Comment: If you don't know what type they'll be, use `object` which is the root type from which everything else in the .Net type system inherits.

Comment: Wow thank you!!! It is working now! Though it takes time.
Do you know about any way to avoid this : y> y< y!=, though to still avoid specific columns?

Comment: You're welcome. Honestly, I'd be very, very surprised if it's the boolean operators causing you performance issues. My guess would be that it's the Select cell / update cell / automation that's causing the problems but it's only a guess. To be sure, you need to attach a (CPU) profiler and run the code.  Visual studio comes with one built in (although I'm not sure it's in _all_ editions). Run it, it will show you how much time was spent on each line of code. Then you know where the problem is and what to optimise. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms182372.aspx to get you started.

Comment: Although, for readability's sake, I'd do the following... `var matches = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 10, 22, 312, ... }; if matches.Contains(someNumber) { /*Do something*/ }`

Comment: I didn't understand the syntax. after the first { i set what matches IS ABLE to be? or what it cannot be, or ...?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear and the thought was half-formed. It was more the idea that you define collection(s) beforehand and then use .Contains(a quick hash lookup) in your loop. You could define two lists, one with all possible ranges and another with exceptions and do something like `if(ranges.contains(x) && !rangeexceptions.contains(y)) { /*...*/}`. You can add ranges to a HashSet like this... `ranges.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(218, 222));`. Note that this was purely a comment on code style and is not significant in resolving your issue. Have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: The program crashes when it reaches the 25th line of the xlsx file. will troubleshoot later.